# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the DATABASE_URL environment variable

Tags: python, django

I annotate text data (building data sets for named entity recognition models) using AlpacaTag, which was designed using Python on Django.
I followed the steps of [AlpacaTag](https://github.com/INK-USC/AlpacaTag/wiki/Installation) installation guide
When I run the command
`python manage.py migrate`
(I come to find information, to know this is the Django's command of database migration),
The program threw an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 367, in get_value
    value = self.ENVIRON[var]
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 86, in wrapped
    saved_locale = translation.get_language()
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 254, in get_language
    return _trans.get_language()
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    if settings.USE_I18N:
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/duzx21/AlpacaTag/annotation/AlpacaTag/app/settings.py", line 33, in <module>
    SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 179, in __call__
    parse_default=parse_default
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 371, in get_value
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY environment variable
```

This is defined in the setting.py file：

```
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')
```

I don't know how to solve this problem, then randomly generated a string of text as the SECRET_KEY：

```
SECRET_KEY='2ap4_#)wk@5)3lsh6idzxwaouy6)*(5z#w(3atk0%a5!+-29j-'
```

It seems to works.
but, when I am running the command again:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

The program throws another very similar exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 367, in get_value
    value = self.ENVIRON[var]
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 86, in wrapped
    saved_locale = translation.get_language()
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 254, in get_language
    return _trans.get_language()
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    if settings.USE_I18N:
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/duzx21/AlpacaTag/annotation/AlpacaTag/app/settings.py", line 33, in <module>
    SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 179, in __call__
    parse_default=parse_default
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 371, in get_value
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY environment variable
(alpacatag) duzx21@d01:~/AlpacaTag/annotation/AlpacaTag$ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 367, in get_value
    value = self.ENVIRON[var]
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DATABASE_URL'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 86, in wrapped
    saved_locale = translation.get_language()
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 254, in get_language
    return _trans.get_language()
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    if settings.USE_I18N:
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/duzx21/AlpacaTag/annotation/AlpacaTag/app/settings.py", line 96, in <module>
    'default': env.db(),
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 280, in db_url
    self.get_value(var, default=default),
  File "/home/duzx21/miniconda3/envs/alpacatag/lib/python3.6/site-packages/environ/environ.py", line 371, in get_value
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the DATABASE_URL environment variable
```

This is defined in the setting.py file：

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': env.db(),

}
```

I tried to change `DATABASE['default']` to

```
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
}
```

The program seems to work, and then I run the command

```
python manage.py migrate
```

It works！
and then I run the command

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Then, enter the admin username and email address and the password and press enter.

```
    Username: admin
Email address: admin@example.com
Password: **********
Password (again): *********
```

and then I run the command

```
python manage.py runserver 8080
```

I can open the Web interface, which according to the author should be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTvVr.png)
But mine is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPcau.png)
I can’t do anything on it, for example, create a project, upload a dataset, these are its most basic functions.
**So my previous modification of the program should not be correct**
This is my setting.py:

```
    """
Django settings for AlpacaTag project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.20.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import environ
from pathlib import Path
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
import dj_database_url


env = environ.Env()
# reading .env file
environ.Env.read_env()

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoprojeckt.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
# Raises django's ImproperlyConfigured exception if SECRET_KEY not in os.environ
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')
# SECRET_KEY='2ap4_#)wk@5)3lsh6idzxwaouy6)*(5z#w(3atk0%a5!+-29j-'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
# False if not in os.environ
DEBUG = env.bool('DEBUG', False)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'server.apps.ServerConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'django_filters',
    'widget_tweaks',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'server/static'),
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases
# Parse database connection url strings like psql://user:pass@127.0.0.1:8458/db
DATABASES = {
    # read os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] and raises ImproperlyConfigured exception if not found
    'default': env.db(),
    # 'default': {
    #     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    #     'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    # }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    # {
    #     'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    # },
    # {
    #     'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    # },
    # {
    #     'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    # },
    # {
    #     'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    # },
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly',
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 5,
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',),
    'SEARCH_PARAM': 'q',
}
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/projects/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
```

**I tried to learn the basics of Django, but I didn't know anything about Web development, or database, and after looking at some of the basics of Django, I still didn't know how to debug this error.**

Comment: Have you set `DATABASE_URL` in django `settings.py`? Take a look at this:
https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter-django/issues/2821#issuecomment-974914681

Comment: I don't know anything about databases or the web, I just clone the project code from Git and I don't know how to set 'DATABASE_URL'

Comment: Your settings.py says: `# read os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] and raises ImproperlyConfigured exception if not found`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `settings.py` it is using `env.db()` which is an alias for `db_url()`. so you need to have a `.env` file near your `settings.py` and a key for `DATABASE_URL` in that file. I prefer making an easier approach. So replace this part:

```
DATABASES = {
    # read os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] and raises ImproperlyConfigured exception if not found
    'default': env.db(),
}
```

with this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
}
```

The problem with your `settings.py` is that it is not specifying `STATIC_ROOT` and since `DEBUG=False`, serving static files will cause you some errors (As you need to `collectstatic` files, that is why your browser shows first page differently). I suggest now that you are running it locally, do this in your `settings.py`:

```
# Search for Debug in your settings and replace with this
DEBUG = True
# Add this one to your settings
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

Comment: There is no .env file.

Comment: I tried your method, and it worked, but as I showed above,I can’t do anything on it, for example, create a project, upload a dataset, these are its most basic functions.

Comment: @puppyDu I found the problem. Use `DEBUG=True` in your `settings.py` to load static data properly. Do as i say above. Updated the answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Glad to be helpful :D Plz upvote!!!!!!!

Comment: I am sorry. I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote.

Answer (score 0):

Just got this error and started with django_environ 0.11.0
Pinned in my requirements to a previous working version:

```
django_environ==0.10.0
```